# Using spherical coordinates for triple integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates, multiple-integral

$ \int_{0}^3 \int_{0}^{\sqrt{9-x^2}} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}}  \frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}{1+x^2+y^2+z^2} \ dz \ dy \ dx$

Using spherical co-ord's this becomes :

$ \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^\pi \int_{0}^3 \frac{r^3\sin(\theta)}{1+r^2} \ dr \ d\theta \ d\phi $

Is this correct? If it is how do I carry on from here?

Answer (score 1):

It looks fine to me, except for the limits of integration. The next step is to write it as$$\frac\pi2\left(\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\sin(\theta)\,\mathrm d\theta\right)\left(\int_0^3\frac{r^3}{1+r^2}\,\mathrm dr\right).$$

Comment: I was just wondering if the limits for the spherical were correct?

Comment: No. I did not notice that you are working on the first octant only. Therefore, both $\phi$ and $\theta$ shoulg go only from $0$ to $\frac\pi2$. I shall edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your limits aren't quite correct. The spherical region you are integrating over is only in the first octant. Therefore $\theta$ should range from 0 to $\pi/2$ and $\phi$ should range from $0$ to $\pi/2$.

Comment: Thanks, how can i show this using the given limits?

Comment: Do you mean how can you compute the integral now? Or do you mean how do you show that the limits on the angles are from $0$ to $\pi/2$?

Comment: I've figured out how to get the limits now thank you, the integral i got in the end was pi/4( 9-ln(10)), could you tell me if this is correct?

Comment: That looks right to me. At this point you should probably accept the answer by  José Carlos Santos.